# Problem with Android Studio 4.0 closes, when opening ic_file.xml in /res/drawable/

Tags: android, android-studio, graphics

I am having problem when I try to open any file from the **/res/drawable/** folder, it starts loading the `ic_file.xml` and android studio closes, this did not happen to me with previous versions of android studio.

The android studio version is:
Android Studio 4.0
Build # AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.7 + 8-LTS amd64
VM: Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 4062M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force = true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.jetbrains.ChooseRuntime, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.intellij.plugins.markdown

Operating system:
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU / Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster

When I run from terminal with `./studio.sh` I get this warning, after trying to open the file in mentioned folder /res/drawable/:

[image]

````
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0  
2020-06-10 12:51:25,437 [   2318]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Firebase Services" is incompatible (until build 192.SNAPSHOT < AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223)   
2020-06-10 12:51:25,805 [   2686]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Kotlin" is incompatible (until build 192.SNAPSHOT < AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223)   
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to field sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.awtAppClassName  
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil  
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations  
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-06-10 12:51:29,285 [   6166]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - List.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation   
2020-06-10 12:51:29,286 [   6167]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Table.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation   
2020-06-10 12:51:29,286 [   6167]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Tree.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation   
2020-06-10 12:51:30,231 [   7112]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk]   
2020-06-10 12:51:34,850 [  11731]   WARN - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - UI freezed for 6735ms, details saved to /home/lui/.AndroidStudio4.0/system/log/threadDumps-freeze-20200610-125128-AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223-AnnotationInvocationHandler.cloneArray-6sec   
2020-06-10 12:51:51,403 [  28284]   WARN - ugins.textmate.TextMateService - Missing builtin bundles, checked: 
/home/lui/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles
/home/lui/android-studio/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles   
2020-06-10 12:51:51,732 [  28613]   WARN - uilder.surface.NlDesignSurface - The mode BOTH is not recognized, use default mode NlScreenMode instead 
2020-06-10 12:51:52,888 [  29769]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider   
2020-06-10 12:55:42,692 [ 259573]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.GradleScriptInputsWatcher$Storage   
2020-06-10 12:55:42,733 [ 259614]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.configuration.utils.ScriptClassRootsStorage   
2020-06-10 12:55:51,413 [ 268294]   WARN - dering.imagepool.ImagePoolImpl - 0 maxSize for Bucket. This Bucket will not be used.   
Unable to find class android/graphics/ColorSpace  
2020-06-10 12:55:52,562 [ 269443]   WARN - .uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader - GraphicsJNI: Unable to find class android/graphics/ColorSpace   
Aborted```
````

Comment: It crashes with no stack trace? If you create a scrap project and copy that resource into it, does Studio crash for that scrap project? If so, perhaps you could file a bug report with the scrap project.

Comment: @C When I create a new project after indexing the indices directly, android studio closes, there I edit so that you see what the console says

Comment: Then I suggest that you file a bug report with that new project and your console output (and, if you are in position to make it, a screencast of your desktop showing Studio's behavior).

Comment: That I report it to Google, do you say? Thank you very much for your prompt response.

Comment: "That I report it to Google, do you say?" -- yes. This behavior is not normal, and the best way to get it fixed is to provide lots of evidence to Google that there is a problem. A project that reproduces the behavior, plus the console output and a screencast, would be a good start.

Comment: Thank you, I'll investigate how to do that for the report because I've never done it.

Comment: Visit https://issuetracker.google.com/issues and click the "Create Issue" button. For the component, choose "Android Public Tracker > App Development > Android Studio". The template will help guide you, and the paperclip button will allow you to add attachments.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Well the way I solve it is by lowering the java version from 11 to 1.8 in my operating system, I don't know if this is a definitive solution to the problem, but with that I stop closing the android studio when opening any type of file *.xml from the res/ folder.   

This version is the one I have now and that currently works:  
`$ java -version`  

`java version "1.8.0_251"`  
`Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)`  
`Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)`